# Assertion property returns null

Tags: testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, assertion

I have developed `Coded UI` support for my `Custom Control` and i have compare assert property value like below,

```
Assert.AreEqual(this.AssertMethod2ExpectedValues.UIZoomResetCustomToolBarIconMargin,
 uIZoomResetCustom.ToolBarIconMargin, "Toolbar margin failed");
```

But `uIZoomResetCustom.ToolBarIconMargin` returns always `null`. How to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to debug the tests and/or highlight the toolbar before reaching the assertion?
It is quite clear that framework is unable to find the toolbar. Maybe you need to tweak the search properties.